# Setting up TestCafe with Rails backend and fixtures data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, testcafe

I'm currently working on a Rails project that uses RSpec as the testing framework. We have different Rails fixture data that helps us test our UI when we're in different states.

However, I've been intrigued with using [TestCafe](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/) to handle our functional UI testing. I've played around with various examples of the website and it seems great to use. But the one part holding me back from introducing it into my project is I'm not sure how to use TestCafe to set up something equivalent to Rails fixture data - i.e. I want to use TestCafe to set up different scenarios where my database is in a particular state so that I can then test the UI.

I've tried searching through TestCafe's documentation but haven't had much luck since TestCafe seems to use the word "fixtures" to represent a particular page you're testing and not the mock data.

Comment: Did you found a solution meanwhile? We are in the same situation currently.

Comment: @phortx unfortunately i haven't found a solution to this yet

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no built-in support for handling test databases. But because tests are executed in Node.js environment, you can use e.g. [db-migrate](https://github.com/db-migrate/node-db-migrate) and [js-yaml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml) modules to load your fixtures to the test database.